# Unable to load shared library when running on .NET interactive on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a code that uses [MKL](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl.html#gs.4rwxdl) native library in a `.ipynb` .NET notebook and I get the following error.

> Error: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libmkl_rt.dylib' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(liblibmkl_rt.dylib, 1): image not found

The code runs as expected if I run it with `dotnet run` but it doesn't on the interactive notebook. What could be the solution? (ps using .NET 5.0)

Comment: Maybe you should try this command? 
`DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES="{here is the dir path to native libraries}" dotnet run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the native libraries into `/usr/local/lib` solved the problem.

Comment: I am new to C#/dotnet - it would be great if you could also add the command to copy the native library to the specified path.